# How to fix a 6 point vertex

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology

I have a character I am modelling and I'm having a little trouble around the mouth. Somehow I've managed to get a 6 point vertex at both corners of the mouth. I know I should resolve this somehow, but I'm not sure what I should do.

I've tried merging the vertices on the other end (the 2 red circles) but that didn't fix it.

[image]

What step should I take from here to resolve this?

Comment: This is odd, merging those two verts _should_ fix the problem. Perhaps the surrounding geometry is too skewed and far apart.

Comment: Could I just ask, what's so bad about a 6 point vertex?

Comment: @iKlsR - RE your first comment, I does reduce the points from 6 to 5, but from there I still don't know.

Comment: @DavidS.- From everything I've seen in tuorials, a point like this is bad practice. I'm trying to clean up my object and have everything in quads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some great resources out there (non-specific to Blender) about how to solve these kinds of problems. I'd recommend looking for some facial modeling tutes that talk about topology specifically.

To answer your question, though, you will have to have a tri or a 5-point vertex :-/ It's a veritable law of facial modeling and there's great debate (apparently) on where the unavoidable tris and 5's should go.

In this case, you'll probably want to make a face out of those three vertices you have circled, to make a tri. This will give you an edge loop that goes around the mouth, which is highly desirable. The debate usually surrounds how far away from the lips that tri should be. It's usually helpful to put the tri somewhere that it will mostly be flat, and won't distort very much. If it's small enough, it might not matter.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I ended up joining those right 2 vertices and adding some more edges to make the corner of the mouth more clean. I didn't get rid of the 5 pointer, but at least the topography is cleaner.

Comment: Cool! I finally found one of the tutes that was particularly helpful to me: http://www.3dtotal.com/index_tutorial_detailed.php?id=858#.Up5IgcSkpN4

Good luck!